# How to affect 2 in directories column for a file ( ls command)

Tags: unix, ls

I'm looking how to affect the value 2 in directories  column inside the ls command for a file.

Actually the value is 1.

I tried to creat a symbolic link but its still 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to creat a symbolic link but its still 1

You need a hardlink instead (i.e. `ln` without `-s`). That number is the count of references to the inode and a symbolic link doesn't increase it.